# How to properly clear VFS Ram filesystem

Tags: java, filesystems, ram, vfs, apache-commons-vfs

I'm using VFS2 to construct an in-memory filesystem (uring the `ram` scheme) for tests. After each test I've to clean up (destroy all created files and folders), I'm using the following command:

```
VFS.getManager().getFilesCache().close();
```

However this doesn't seem to clear everything! what's the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Javadoc FileCache only closes the cache.

```
FileSystemManager manager = VFS.getManager();
FileObject root = manager.resolveFile("ram:/");
manager.closeFileSystem(root.getFileSystem());
```

The last line clears the filecache of the filesystem and will close the filesystem passed in

Comment: the `FilesCache.close()` javadoc says that it purges the whole cache!

Comment: This works for direct archives. For archives inside archives it is not clearing the cache. For eg. jar:zip:file:///test.zip/a.jar